# How to contact author of CartoDB map?

Tags: carto

I am a student at college and recently listened Colorado Public Radio about Meth Possession Arrests. I am interested in obtaining the data if the map creator would like to share it with me for GIS class project about crime in Denver.

Is this possible? Is there a way to leave a question/request for a map author in CartoDB?

Comment: I don't believe he is a user on this site, and even if so we don't really work like that. If you'd like to edit the question to focus on where to find such data rather than contacting him, that would be best. A quick search turned up an actual online article version for that CPR report, and there are links there that should put you in contact with him: https://www.cpr.org/news/story/meth-use-colorado-has-police-and-outreach-groups-scrambling No idea what his specific data source(s) were (article cites local PDs), but several cities/counties in this area have downloadable crime data sets.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it currently reads as a personal contact request rather than a specific data request. Revising to link to the map in question and request only data or sources would bring it on-topic for GIS.SE.

Comment: Contact your local authorities and ask for the data. Ask nicely and explain your intentions and they should be able to give you a clip of it with any sensitive and/or personal information removed; your country may have a *freedom of information* act which should make government data available. It is possible that they might want to charge a processing fee for handling the data, be prepared for that.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question to me: "Is there a way to contact the author of a CartoDB map"?

Comment: @SteveBennett That does seem perfectly reasonable, and as I read over it again I can now get that interpretation. Originally I wasn't picking up on that given the wording, specific name, and the use of the data tag. Nice catch/my bad. I've rephrased things and voted to reopen, since that does seem to be the asker's intent. It might be better solved at CartoDB's website/help, but I know there are some employees on here and someone else might know.

Comment: To answer the question (since I can't actually create an answer), it looks like the only way is to place a comment at the bottom of a map, using the Disqus comment feature. It's not clear how or if the author is notified of the comment.

Comment: @SteveBennett I've re-opened this so that you can add that as an answer.  I thought the user was trying to contact the map author using GIS SE tools but the re-phrasing seems more along the lines of how to use CartoDB to try and contact one of its map authors.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the only way to contact the author of a CartoDB map is to place a comment at the bottom of a map, using the Disqus comment feature.

[image]

It doesn't seem to (immediately) notify the author of your comment though, from my quick test.